# error_log('doing code');

Tags: php

What is the purpose of error log in php?  I am running the dredit sample php and "doing code" keeps on displaying.

Here's the code:

```
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    error_log('doing code');
    /**
     * Redeemed authorization codes are stored in the session to prevent
     * accidental multiple redemption of the same code causing an exception.
     * ie, if a user refreshes their browser when a code is in the URL.
     * We need to initialize the array of redeemed authorization codes.
     */
    if (!isset($_SESSION['redeemed_codes'])) {
      $_SESSION['redeemed_codes'] = array();
    }
```

Can anyone help me on this? thanks!

Comment: Before typing a question about php, check the manual.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) the error_log is to "send an error message somewhere".

```
bool error_log(string $message [, int $message_type = 0 [, string $destination [, string $extra_headers ]]])
```

If no `$destination` is set, it will just log to the standard error.log, such as `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Your code is just logging to the standard `error_log` that it is `'doing code'` which is just a string. It does nothing, so I assume you are supposed to write your own code inside de if block.

As for `error_log` in general, it's a good way to log error messages, but you can also log to your own logfiles for debugging purposes.

Comment: please correct me if i'm wrong, in this code.. 
the error_log does nothing. so even there's no error.. the 'Doing code' string will dsplay?

Comment: It does something. It logs the string "doing code" to the `error_log`. But you are right that it's done regardless if there's an error or not. You can safely remove this line, and it won't affect your code.

Comment: Thanks!  I deleted this part of code to run the Dredit PHP files. But it gets error. Was thinking if it affects something! thanks!

Comment: If the question is resolved, feel free to mark my answer. Thanks.